# Is the derived set of the intersection of two sets contained in the intersection of the derived sets?

Tags: general-topology

Given a topological set (X, $\tau$), and A and B subsets of X, is it true that

(A $\cap$ B)' $\subseteq$ A' $\cap$ B'

I know that (A $\cup$ B)' = A' $\cup$ B', but I don't know how to derived the result from here.

Comment: mmh... your example leads to [1,2] $\subseteq $ [1,2], doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in (A\cap B)'$. Then every open neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A\cap B$, hence intersects both $A$ and $B$. By the first, we conclude t$x\in A'$, by the second $x\in B'$, so $x\in A'\cap B'$. This shows
$$ (A\cap B)'\subseteq A'\cap B'.$$
In gerenal, we do not have equality, as witnessed in $X=\Bbb R$ by $A=\Bbb Q$, $B=\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ or by $A=[0,1)$, $B=[1,2]$.

Comment: @Haegn vom eitzen,....when is equality true? Can I say that when two sets are not mutually disjoint then equality holds?